# Cannot remove delegate calendar access via PowerShell in o365

Tags: powershell, office365, calendar

I read the Microsoft documentation and this is supposed to be the command:

```
set-mailboxfolderpermission userA@contoso.com:\calendar -user userB@contoso.com -accessrights editor -sharingpermissionflags none
```

**userA** is admin, PowerShell is logged into exchange admin with **userA**'s account.  **userA**'s calendar permissions are: *userA-owner; userB-editor-delegate*.

I get no error and the `get` command still shows the delegate flag.  I've also removed the user and re-added but the flag is still there.

I am the exchange administrator using an "admin" account (according to goDaddy).  The host is not Microsoft but GoDaddy's o365 abomination.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since the commentary has gotten to a point where it isn't useful anymore, which I am to blame for, I have simply deleted my commentary.  You can disregard my original comment.  However, in the future I hope you use the tools to reopen questions, instead of submitting the same question again.

Comment: I understand.  I'm glad we worked this out together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the fix:

1. Go into the calendar owner's Outlook application or add their account to your Outlook.
2. Go to File > Account Settings > Delegate Access.
3. Remove the user.
4. Re-add the user's permission to the calendar via PowerShell or GUI options.